# creating jquery functions and using them for html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

im trying to create this function in javascript but its not working, im a bit new to js, so i don't what im really doing wrong here.

the code:

```
<div id="test">TESTING</div>
```

JS:

```
function animateDiv(div){

var text = $('#' + div + '"').text();

var doAnimate = function() {
    $('span').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
                .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
        },that.index()*100);
    });
}

$('#' + div + "'").html('');

for(i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
  $('#' + div + "'").append('<span>'+text[i]+'</span>');
    if(i==text.length-1) doAnimate();
  }

}
  // using the function here to run animation on div test from html  
 animateDiv(test);
```

the jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/aA8Un/3/

Comment: its more this function is not working i dont know why sort of question. i clarified this at the top.

Comment: define "not working".  Your fiddle seems fine.

Comment: the version I saw was working, but it was different code to what you had posted here.

Comment: its noot a problem, thanks for helping, the question has been answered now!!

Comment: please be more careful next time.  The code posted here had obvious flaws, but your question was lousy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/aA8Un/8/) works now

```
function animateDiv(div){

var text = $('#' + div.id).text();

var doAnimate = function() {
    $('span').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
                .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
        },that.index()*100);
    });
}

$('#' + div.id).html('');

for(i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
  $('#' + div.id).append('<span>'+text[i]+'</span>');
    if(i==text.length-1) doAnimate();
  }

}

 animateDiv(test);
```

Actually you were trying to concatenate a string and an object by this `$("#"+div)`, which is wrong, you should do this `$("#"+div.id)` which is legal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function using single/double quotes like

```
animateDiv("test");
```

instead of

```
animateDiv(test);
```

And remove '"' from your code everywhere

So Make it `$('#' + div + '"')` to `$('#' + div)`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aA8Un/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('#' + div + '"').text();
```

replace with

```
var text = $('#' + div).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `animateDiv('test')`
2. subsitute `$('#' + div + '"') with  $('#' + div)`